# How can I control Google Map's GMSMapView animated layer on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a `GMSMapView` view in my `UIViewController` view hierarchy. When I click a button to change the size of the whole layout, both my layout and `GMSMapView` animate their layers. However, it seems that the map layer of `GMSMapView` is animating with a different speed than other content like the Google Maps logo. This creates a visible empty space temporarily at the bottom/at the top until the animations finish, which is ugly. Is there any way to control the animation speed of this layer inside of `GMSMapView`?

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to just change the background to be consistent with your map color (like a dark background) to just minimize that empty space?

Comment: @Yrll I can't change the design of mine, and I am unable to control the background color of Google's views.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Then filing a bug would be nice. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer to the animation problem, [in version 8.3.0](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/release-notes) the `GMSMapView` can be initialised with a [GMSMapViewOptions.backgroundColor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/configure-map#map_options). This allows me to *hide* the ugly `UIColor.lightGray` default and makes the animation glitch less perceptible.